# react-router v3 root route renders 2 components. How to do it in with react-router v5?

Tags: reactjs

#### react-router v3 version

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={Common}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} ></IndexRoute>
    <Route path='list(/:id)' component={List}></Route>
    <Redirect from='detail' to='list/123'></Redirect>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

This is the code I use with react-router v5, but the Home component does not render

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Redirect path='/' exact component={Common}/>
    <Route path='/list(/:id)' component={List}/>
    <Redirect from='/detail' to='/list/123'/>
    <Redirect component={Home}></Redirect>
</BrowserRouter>
```

What should I do to get the same behavior as react-router v3?

Comment: I suppose you are redirecting anypath that doesnt match with your list of routes to _Home_ Component?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about the version you are talking about, as I am also pretty new to the React Ecosystem. However, when I tried from my end, I tried to define my React router in the below fashion. Maybe it would be helpful for you.  I hope you are trying to use Webpack where you might have defined devServer: { historyApiFallback: true }

```
<BrowseRouter>
 <Switch>
 <Route path="/" exact={true} component={component1} />
 <Route path="/create" component={component2} />
 <Route path="/edit/:id" component={component3} />
 <Route component={pagenotfound} />
</Switch>
</BrowseRouter>
```

Regards 
Pavan Bhamidipati

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `Redirect`. Simply use `Route` component.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/list/123">List</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/list(/:id)" component={List} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function List() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>List</h2>
    </div>
  );
}



export default BasicExample;
```